# How do I make a flowchart using markdown on my github blog

Tags: github, markdown

I recently put some posts on my github jekyll blog.Everything is fine,except my flowchart.I used to make flowchart like this:

````
```flow
my content
```
````

but when I preview the post,It can't display as a flowchart.
This is Ok in some other markdown editor.If I want to make flowchart on my github blog,what can I do?Thanks.

Comment: There is an official recommendation from GitHub (Sept. 2021): see [my edited answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34836640/6309)

Comment: Feb. 2022: this is officially supported. See my [updated answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34836640/6309.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Update Feb. 2022: the Mermaid support is official (for [Gist too](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-02-28-gists-now-support-mermaid-diagrams/)):

[image: https://github.blog/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/mvp2.png?resize=1200%2C630]

*Alternative Links 17/02/2020:*

```
graph TD;
    A-->B;
    A-->C;
    B-->D;
    C-->D;
```

[image: Diagram From Help Page]

*There is also an entry in the [GitHub Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/working-with-advanced-formatting/creating-diagrams)*

Working with [**Knut Sveidqvist**](https://github.com/knsv) and also the wider community at **[CommonMark](https://commonmark.org/)**, we’ve rolled out a change that will allow you to create graphs inline using [Mermaid syntax](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/n00b-syntaxReference?id=syntax-structure), for example:

---

Update Sept. 2021: from [GitHub tweet](https://twitter.com/github/status/1441378096096051200):

> Need to add some ASCII art flow diagrams to your README or code comments?
>
> YES → https://asciiflow.com (งツ)ว

[image: flowchart]

This is not "markdown" per se, using "extended ASCII", but it can do the job.

---

Original answer 2016: The [GitHub Flavored Markdown (GFM)](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown/) alone does not support flowcharts (as opposed of other markdown like [mermaid](https://github.com/mermaid-js/mermaid)). You can confirm it in this [GFM editor](https://jbt.github.io/markdown-editor).

You would be better served by using some JavaScript library to display flowcharts.

As [commented below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34836305/how-do-i-make-a-flowchart-using-markdown-on-my-github-blog/34836640#comment106440601_34836640) by [Jeremiah England](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9849440/jeremiah-england), there is:

- a [`github/markup` issue 533](https://github.com/github/markup/issues/533), with a [possible workaround](https://github.com/github/markup/issues/533#issuecomment-372833846)
- a [feature request](https://github.community/t5/How-to-use-Git-and-GitHub/Feature-Request-Support-Mermaid-markdown-graph-diagrams-in-md/td-p/21967), which also includes workarounds:

  - a [Chrome extension](https://github.com/BackMarket/github-mermaid-extension)
  - a [GitHub Action](https://github.com/neenjaw/mermaid-markdown-test)

Comment: why doesn't GitHub support flowcharts?

Comment: @AllenVork I don't know, but I suspect GitHub support might have more to say about that feature support (or lack thereof).

Comment: @AllenVork It looks like there's a [feature request for it](https://github.community/t5/How-to-use-Git-and-GitHub/Feature-Request-Support-Mermaid-markdown-graph-diagrams-in-md/td-p/21967) on the github community forum.

Comment: @JeremiahEngland Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visiblity, and added more links to potential workarounds.

Comment: Hi @VonC, one problem with `mermaid` it is not supporting other languages, e.g., Bengali, Hindi.

Comment: @BiMo I do not see anywhere in [mermaids documentation](https://mermaid.js.org/config/configuration.html) mentions of any language supported though.

Comment: exactly, I also googled a bit. It would be really nice though.

Comment: P.S. Chinese and Japanese languages are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following Jekyll [plugin](https://github.com/jasonbellamy/jekyll-mermaid) in order to print the flowchart in your Jekyll blog.